# Ruby On Rails Rescue block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have method

common method

```rb
def error_notification 
  <notification_code>
end
```

whenever the code catches an exception I need to call this method in the rescue block

eg: example

```rb
def error_method
  begin
    <some_code>
  rescue => e
    error_notification
  end
end
```

Instead of calling all rescue blocks, there is any standard way to write the code

Comment: What part, do you think, is not standard?

Answer (score 0):

While what you have shown is in no way out of the normal realm of things but you could can certainly DRY this up a bit if you are using it frequently by creating a wrapper for the calls.

Simple Example:

```
def guard(&block) 
  begin 
    block.call 
  rescue => e 
    error_notification
  end
end
```

Then use where needed as

```
def error_method
  guard do 
   some_code 
  end 
end
```

That being said generally you would want to rescue specific errors not every `StandardError` but that design decision is up to you.

Additionally if this is specific to controller methods (you didn't really specify), `ActiveSupport` offers a method called `rescue_from` that you could utilize as well and would generally be considered more idiomatic in rails application [Docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

For Example your setup would look like

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: error_notification

  private 
    def error_notification 
      notification_code
    end
end
```